# Aligning text in multicols environment. \raggedright does not work

Tags: alignment

I have been trying to left-align some justified text in the multicols environment with no success. I have tried to input \raggedright and \RaggedRight pretty much at every place I could think of. I also came across an answer by the user lockstep recommending this line of code:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{multicols}{\RaggedRight}
```

I tried using this as well, but it does not help

Here is some example code showing this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{multicols}{\RaggedRight}

\title{multicol alignment}
\author{Jonas}
\date{May 2022}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \blindtext
    \columnbreak
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textheight]{image.png}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Which only produces this output where the text is still justified and not left-aligned:

[image]

Comment: You have applied `\centering` to the text over-writing the raggedright.  The text is not justified, as your post shows. Leave a blank line before `\centering` so it only applies to the image

Comment: Cheers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is unrelated to `multicol` as can be seen in this simplified example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March

\bigskip

aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
aaa bbb ccc one two three January February March
\centering

XXX

\end{document}
```

Linebreaking happens at the end of the paragraph with the settings in force at that point. So here, the first paragraph is set ragged right, but `\centering` was issued before the second paragraph (formally) ended, so it is set centered, even though it appears before `\centering`.

If you end the paragraph with a blank line before issuing `\centering` then it would be set ragged, with the centering just applying to the following XXX.